# How do I insert radio buttons in Numbers for iPad?

Tags: ipad, numbers

I need to insert radio buttons on a Numbers spreadsheet. I tried importing an Excel document with form radio buttons, but it did not pull through. Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something we can do to help improve the answer provided?

Comment: @bmike Last seen seven hours after the question was asked; I doubt we'll be seeing them again. :( I wish we could accept answers for other people in cases like this where the answer is unambiguously, universally correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead radio buttons by double tapping the cell you wish to enter one and then under either the '42' or '=' option you can select true/false. When you check this it will add a radio button or tick box, you can choose which one under the 'i'

I have done this on my iPad so will edit later when I can upload a screen shot.